# Use TOR on Raspberry PI - Tails RDP

Tags: anonymity, configuration, tails, raspberry-pi

Currently I am trying to do the following on a remote-controlled desktop

1. I installed Tor on a Raspberry Pi and made the setup as a Access point
2. On Windows I can make a remote desktop and it will log the IP address that Tor assigns me
3. When using Tails I installed remmina RDP, however I can't make a remote desktop session.

The project is to try to use an OS like Tails to do RDP in a controlled environment, it seems that Tails blocks it, but we would want to know if there is a way to de-anonimize the RDP on Tails and force it to use Tor on the Raspberry Pi. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't think this is a Tor question and this issue is most likely due to the encryption requirements of RDP setup (2003 vs 2012). Take a look at some of these that might help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop

Comment: I advice you to check-out ODROID-H2+ board whenever you want to run a Tor relay.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure but have you tried editing the torrc file on tails to set a control port

```
Example: Set pi torrc to 127.0.0.1:<What ever port you wanna use rdp>
```

as you know it sets a localhost for connection to tor via anyone ip on network

set tails upon setup tor

```
click "My network uses a proxy via web access", while youre connected to youre pi ad pi's 127.0.0.<number ur pc on access points>:<That port you set in pi for connection localhost>
```

this allows you to use PI's tor network as access point instead of tails setting localhost upont start up from this point any Controled envirnment apps via the PI points set ip to localhost and the port you set

The reason tails has security to not access localhost apps incomming connections is upon start its set to use tails torrc file directly  so what the above does is it allows you to use youre PI acces point as tails's local ip before it connects to tor so from this point you can rdp to any pc on local host or use net by using youre ip

```
127.0.0.<number ur pc on access points>:<That port you set in pi for connection localhost>
```

Contact

```
Jabber: OverClock "@" jabber . ru
```